# Installing wxpthon on pydroid3

Tags: python, python-3.x, wxpython

Error installing wxpthon on pydroid3

I tried using pip to install wxpthon, the build process went well for it's dependencies but it failed to build with some sort of error about a subprocess.

Comment: Please post the error or any other details that might help in you question.

Comment: Here's the error. Finished command: build (0m32.971s)
  Command '"/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/bin/python3.9" -u build.py build' failed with exit code 1.
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully..... Failed to build wxPython
ERROR: Failed to build one or more wheels

Answer (score 0):

There's a problem with the version compatibility, as `python3.10` is not supporting it. If you are using that version, Then may be downgrading it can help. Or you can try some of the below steps to install it.

Try installing using -

```
 pip install wheel
 pip install pygame
 pip install -U wxPython
```

You can read more about the installation [here](https://wiki.wxpython.org/How%20to%20install%20wxPython#Installing_wxPython-Phoenix_using_pip).

You can check the "official" list of prerequisites from [the wxWidgets source](https://github.com/wxWidgets/Phoenix/blob/master/README.rst#prerequisites) - You need to have those dependencies installed.

You might need to install wheel package (Check the version of wxpython and the version of python you have in your machine) -

```
pip install wxPython_Phoenix-3.0.3.dev2811+ecc4797-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
```

Wheels:

Python 3.8: https://github.com/josephsl/wxpy32whl/releases/download/4.2.0/wxPython-4.2.0-cp38-cp38-win32.whl

Python 3.9: https://github.com/josephsl/wxpy32whl/releases/download/4.2.0/wxPython-4.2.0-cp39-cp39-win32.whl

Python 3.10: https://github.com/josephsl/wxpy32whl/releases/download/4.2.0/wxPython-4.2.0-cp310-cp310-win32.whl

Python 3.11: https://github.com/josephsl/wxpy32whl/releases/download/4.2.0/wxPython-4.2.0-cp311-cp311-win32.whl

You can checkout this [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/wxWidgets/Phoenix/issues/2235)

Comment: I'm currently using python 3.9

Comment: Ok, check this - https://github.com/wxWidgets/Phoenix/issues/2235